# Search functionality using multiple search inputs for Razor page ASP.NET Core web application SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I am new to ASP.NET and C# and this is my first project

I have a page `Purchaseditems.cshtml` which has multiple search columns for 10 fields. The data is held in `dbo.purchased` table.

Presently, I can search the database using separately for the 10 columns. However, I am not able to figure out how to execute the search using multiple inputs for search. For instance, I can presently either search by *Serial Description* or by *SNo* at a time. I want to search by both columns simultaneously so as to make it like a filter.

Any help/guidance is appreciated

TIA

My code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace PCERM.Pages.FOAL_Management_System.Purchased_List
{
    public class PurchaseditemsModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<purchasedinfo> purchaselist = new List<purchasedinfo>();
        public string search1 = "";
        public string search2 = "";
        public string search3 = "";
        public string search4 = "";
        public string search5 = "";
        public string search6 = "";
        public string search7 = "";
        public string search8 = "";
        public string search9 = "";
        public string search10 = "";
        
        public void OnGet()
        {
            search1 = Request.Query["search1"];
            search2 = Request.Query["search2"];
            search3 = Request.Query["search3"];
            search4 = Request.Query["search4"];
            search5 = Request.Query["search5"];
            search6 = Request.Query["search6"];
            search7 = Request.Query["search7"];
            search8 = Request.Query["search8"];
            search9 = Request.Query["search9"];
            search10 = Request.Query["search10"];

            if (search1 == null) search1 = "";
            if (search2 == null) search2 = "";
            if (search3 == null) search3 = "";
            if (search4 == null) search4 = "";
            if (search5 == null) search5 = "";
            if (search6 == null) search6 = "";
            if (search7 == null) search7 = "";
            if (search8 == null) search8 = "";
            if (search9 == null) search9 = "";
            if (search10 == null) search10 = "";

            try
            {
                string connectionstring = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PCERM;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased ORDER BY itemid2";


                    if (search1.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE serno2 LIKE @search1 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search2.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE sername2 LIKE @search2 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search3.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE department2 LIKE @search3 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search4.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE section2 LIKE @search4 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search5.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE category2 LIKE @search5 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search6.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE pccategory2 LIKE @search6 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search7.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE actualitem2 LIKE @search7 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search8.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE actualvendor2 LIKE @search8 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search9.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE transactionstatus2 LIKE @search9 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    if (search10.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE storestatus2 LIKE @search10 ORDER BY itemid2";
                    }

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search1","%" + search1 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search2","%" + search2 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search3","%" + search3 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search4","%" + search4 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search5","%" + search5 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search6","%" + search6 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search7","%" + search7 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search8","%" + search8 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search9","%" + search9 + "%");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search10","%" + search10 + "%");

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                purchasedinfo purchaseinfo = new purchasedinfo();
                                purchaseinfo.itemid2 = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                purchaseinfo.serno2 = reader.GetInt32(1);
                                purchaseinfo.sername2 = reader.GetString(2);
                                purchaseinfo.qty2 = reader.GetInt32(3);
                                purchaseinfo.unit2 = reader.GetString(4);
                                purchaseinfo.lastprice2 = reader.GetInt32(5);
                                purchaseinfo.vendorname2 = reader.GetString(6);
                                purchaseinfo.department2 = reader.GetString(7);
                                purchaseinfo.section2 = reader.GetString(8);
                                purchaseinfo.category2 = reader.GetInt32(9);
                                purchaseinfo.pccategory2 = reader.GetString(10);
                                purchaseinfo.invoicevalue2 = reader.GetInt32(11);
                                purchaseinfo.invoicedate2 = reader.GetDateTime(12).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                purchaseinfo.actualitem2 = reader.GetString(13);
                                purchaseinfo.actualrate2 = reader.GetInt32(14);
                                purchaseinfo.actualquantity2 = reader.GetInt32(15);
                                purchaseinfo.availmoney2 = reader.GetInt32(16);
                                purchaseinfo.actualprice2 = reader.GetInt32(17);
                                purchaseinfo.actualvendor2 = reader.GetString(18);
                                purchaseinfo.transactionstatus2 = reader.GetString(19);
                                purchaseinfo.storestatus2 = reader.GetString(20);
                                purchaseinfo.invoicefilename2 = reader.GetString(21);
                                purchaseinfo.imagefilename2 = reader.GetString(22);

                                purchaselist.Add(purchaseinfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class purchasedinfo
    {
        public int itemid2 { get; set; }
        public int serno2 { get; set; }
        public string sername2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int qty2 { get; set; }
        public string unit2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int lastprice2 { get; set; }
        public string vendorname2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string department2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string section2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int category2 { get; set; }
        public string pccategory2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int invoicevalue2 { get; set; }
        public string invoicedate2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string actualitem2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int actualrate2 { get; set; }
        public int actualquantity2 { get; set; }
        public int availmoney2 { get; set; }
        public int actualprice2 { get; set; }
        public string actualvendor2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string transactionstatus2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string storestatus2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string invoicefilename2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string imagefilename2 { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

My page:

```
@page
@model PCERM.Pages.FOAL_Management_System.Purchased_List.PurchaseditemsModel

@{
}

<br>

<h2 class=" my-3 text-center">LIST OF PURCHASED/COMPLETED SERIALS</h2>

<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col">
         <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:75px" name="search1" value="@Model.search1" placeholder="S.No">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:165px" name="search2" value="@Model.search2" placeholder="Serial Description">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:125px" name="search3" value="@Model.search3" placeholder="Department">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:100px" name="search4" value="@Model.search4" placeholder="Section">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:105px" name="search5" value="@Model.search5" placeholder="Category">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:230px" name="search6" value="@Model.search6" placeholder="Permanent/Consumable">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:160px" name="search7" value="@Model.search7" placeholder="Purchased Item">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:140px" name="search8" value="@Model.search8" placeholder="Final Vendor">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:170px" name="search9" value="@Model.search9" placeholder="Transaction Status">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" style="width:140px" name="search10" value="@Model.search10" placeholder="Store Status">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>


<table class="table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border:none">
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Item ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Serial No</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Serial Description</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Original Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Unit</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Last Purchased Price</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Suggested Vendor</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Department</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Section</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Category</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Permanent/ Consumable</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Invoice Value</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Invoice Date</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Item Purchased</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Actual Rate</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Quantity Purchased</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Actual Price</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Available Money</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Purchased From</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Transaction Status</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Store Status</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Upload</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">Action</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.purchaselist)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.itemid2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.serno2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.sername2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.qty2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.unit2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.lastprice2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.vendorname2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.department2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.section2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.category2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.pccategory2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.invoicevalue2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.invoicedate2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.actualitem2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.actualrate2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.actualquantity2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.actualprice2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.availmoney2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.actualvendor2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.transactionstatus2</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">@item.storestatus2</td>
                <td style="white-space:normal ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Upload Invoice</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" style=" margin-top:5px">Upload Image</a>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:normal ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Details</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style=" margin-top:5px">Remove Item</a>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:normal ; border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" >View Invoice</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style=" margin-top:5px">View Image</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried manipulating the if statements but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are *replacing* the query in each case rather than filtering based on additional columns. You need to dynamically build the full query, like so:

```cs
var clauses = new List<string>();

if (search1.Length > 0)
{
    clauses.Add("column1 LIKE @search1");
}

if (search2.Length > 0)
{
    clauses.Add("column2 LIKE @search2");
}

// So on so forth, for each filter/column pair...

var filter = string.Join(" AND ", clauses);
var query = $"SELECT * FROM purchased WHERE {filter} ORDER BY itemid2";

// Execute query
```